# API request into a dictionary

Tags: python, hash-map

I have the code below which currently pulls pricing data for Ethereum from CoinGecko API. From this request I am building a dictionary that contains the pieces of information and returning it to be used elsewhere in my code.

This function works fine, but I can't help think it could be written so much shorter than this.

How could this be written differently and shorter?

```
def get_ethereum_data():
    ethereum_data = {}
    response = requests.get(f"{COINGECKO_COIN_URL}")
    response.raise_for_status()
    data = response.json()
    ethereum_data["current_price"] = data["market_data"]["current_price"]["usd"]
    ethereum_data["market_cap"] = data["market_data"]["market_cap"]["usd"]
    ethereum_data["ath"] = data["market_data"]["ath"]["usd"]
    ethereum_data["ath_percentage"] = data["market_data"]["ath_change_percentage"]["usd"]
    ethereum_data["24h_percentage"] = data["market_data"]["price_change_percentage_24h"]
    ethereum_data["7d_percentage"] = data["market_data"]["price_change_percentage_7d"]
    ethereum_data["30d_percentage"] = data["market_data"]["price_change_percentage_30d"]
    ethereum_data["1y_percentage"] = data["market_data"]["price_change_percentage_1y"]
    return ethereum_data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a little bit simpler:

- Inline the returned `ethereum_data` dictionary, return it directly
- `COINGECKO_COIN_URL` is the same as `f"{COINGECKO_COIN_URL}"` (assuming it's a string)
- Extract the frequently used `data["market_data"]` as `market_data = data["market_data"]`

Like this:

```
def get_ethereum_data():
    response = requests.get(COINGECKO_COIN_URL)
    response.raise_for_status()

    data = response.json()    
    market_data = data["market_data"]
    
    return {
        "current_price": market_data["current_price"]["usd"],
        "market_cap": market_data["market_cap"]["usd"],
        "ath": market_data["ath"]["usd"],
        "ath_percentage": market_data["ath_change_percentage"]["usd"],
        "24h_percentage": market_data["price_change_percentage_24h"],
        "7d_percentage": market_data["price_change_percentage_7d"],
        "30d_percentage": market_data["price_change_percentage_30d"],
        "1y_percentage": market_data["price_change_percentage_1y"],
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this doesn't look as repetitive as what I have written out. Also, good catch on the f string, that must be habit.